# How to completly disable angular html escape (app wide)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-sce

I have tried this :

```
angular.module('dashboard').config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', '$httpProvider', '$sceProvider',
        function($ocLazyLoadProvider, $httpProvider, $sceProvider) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
}]);
```

But nothing seems to happen. `&gt;` is escaped by angular even with the so called sce app wide disablement. I can't seem to find anything besides the $sceProvider that could stop angular auto encoding html entities.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? I don't think that globally disabling escaping is a solution to anything.

Comment: @Bergi It is a problem since every encoding is done server side ...

Comment: Don't mix up encoding and escaping! Also, are you sure that all data goes through the server at all?

Comment: Yes, the response from the server includes the encoded html character ">" (encoded as &gt;) . Angular seems to be encoding it again ... I don't know why the shift of security on client side ... One of the headaches when going for a "popular" tools. When client should be a no brainer job ...

Comment: Sorry for the missleading title which included "escape" term. Yes, encoding was the good term here, changed

Comment: No, that was just the wrong term. And yes, if you trust (all?!) your html coming from the server, then you should just state that instead of disabling security.